# What is the standard for when to escape text in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style, escaping, standards

I have a user input field which will be stored into a 'tinytext' field in a MySQL database; pretty standard stuff. I am wondering if there is some sort of standard or best-practice to adhere to when it comes to escaping html special characters using the php function `htmlentities()`?

Should I use `htmlentities()` before I store the data in the database or should I run the function on the data ever time it is output from the website?

Comment: @John Conde, bit of a newb question but how do you do that thing to make inline code look good? I was trying to and couldn't figure it out :P

Comment: Just edit your question and you'll see how I formatted it. I just added backticks ` around any text I wanted to highlighh as code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually no reason to use `htmlentities()` at all any more. Just store everything in UTF-8 fields and adhere to [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

When outputting unsafe user input as HTML, use `htmlspecialchars()`, ideally at the time of output so you have a copy of the original data.

Comment: Good point about having a copy of the original data, good practice to keep good records